# How to delete duplicate values in a report using distinct

Tags: sql, report, distinct

This is my query

```
TTITLE CENTER 'Customer / Title Information'
REPHEADER CENTER 'Customer Order Evaluation' SKIP 3
REPFOOTER SKIP 4 CENTER 'Internal Use Only'
set linesize 75
set pagesize 200
COLUMN "Book Cost" FORMAT $99.99

SELECT  DISTINCT title "Book Title", lastname "Last Name",
        firstname "First Name", cost "Book Cost"
FROM customers JOIN
     orders
     USING (customer#) JOIN
     orderitems
     USING (order#) JOIN
     books
     USING (isbn)
ORDER BY title;
```

I would just like to know how to delete the duplicate values in the title coloumn because the keyword distinct is not doing so.

THank you

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want the same title to show up more than once, use `GROUP BY title`.  It will omit some users too.

DISTINCT will omit duplicate rows, but changes in e.g. name will produce a distinct row, but with the same title.